# In-App Purchase Change Inside the app

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store

Is it possible to change an in-app purchase from inside the app?

I have a tier based setup

Tier 1 - Tier 2 - Tier 3

Say Tier 1 price is $.99, then Tier 2 price is $1.99, then $2.99

Let's say a user bought Tier 1 for $.99, then I wanted to change Tier 2 From $1.99 to $1.29. ONLY IF the user only bought the first Tier.

How would I go about this? If I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the tier's price, only pick from existing once. Perhaps you could make several products with different prices and offer one or another depending on the purchase history.

For example, your Product X may cost $2.99 full price, but Discounted Product X would cost $1.99 and be offered only if the user has purchased other products.

Comment: This is one of the few basic App items I am not familiar with, so thank you! This is much appreciated!